# Is there a way to create something like a file link that doesn't share read/write permission with original files in windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

**Background**:
I have a Windows program that needs to read from a certain set of data files to work. This program does not actually make changes to the data files but it locks the files when running. I currently need to run multiple instances of this program with the same data and don't want to duplicate them because they are big. This program can accept arguments to specify data files path But I don't have access to the source code.
**What I want**:
Is there any way to make something like hard links or symbolic links that don't share read/write permissions with the original file so that I can make multiple instances of this program possible? As for the changes to the links (if any), it's okay for the solution to either ditch them completely or write back at some point.

Comment: Maybe Docker for Windows with Windows containers could help contain the locks. Whether that could work depends on what software you’re running (GUI/CLI).

Answer (score 0):

You need a third-party program for unlocking exclusively accessed files.

Most unlock products solve the problem by locating the locking
program
and forcefully closing its file-handle, in effect preventing
the program from further using the file. This does not help in your case.

Below are a couple of such products that don't seem to solve the problem
by closing file-handles. You will need to try to see if one of them
helps with your problem:

- [IObit Unlocker](http://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php)
- [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/)

If both programs fail, the only solution for running N copies
of the program would be to make N copies of the files in N
separate folders, and call each program instance with a different
folder.